# Start Delayed Job on Mac Reboot / Startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, delayed-job, launchd

I've got a simple app deployed to a Mac mini running 10.5.8

How would I go about restarting the Delayed Job worker anytime the computer is restarted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

launchd is most likely what you want:

http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html